# Can I model model.a>= max(f(model.x1), g(model.x2)) as constraint in PYOMO

Tags: pyomo

model.a, model.x1 and model.x2 are three variables, f and g are two function. I try to formulate like this to make code concise, but get errors

Answer (score 0):

This book may be a useful reference as background for mathematical programming: https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Model+Building+in+Mathematical+Programming%2C+5th+Edition-p-9781118443330

As for the question, simply `a >= f(x1)` and `a >= g(x2)` should suffice in this case.